# How can you return a dynamically typed object in Typescript / Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, generics, dynamictype

I am trying to create a modal generator service. Ultimately, I would like to use it to creative various types of modals.

I have a function to create modal components, and I would like it to accept various types of modal components as input, and return a ComponentRef< (modaltype) > as output. The problem is that I am having some trouble with the syntax.

The problem, specifically, is the function declaration. This is what it looks like right now:

```
private createModalComponent (compType : Type<Component>, vCref: ViewContainerRef): ComponentRef<compType> { ... }
```

This is giving me the error that "cannot find name 'compType'", which makes sense. So I also tried a more generic approach:

```
private createModalComponent<T> (compType : T, vCref: ViewContainerRef): ComponentRef<T> { ... }
```

But that gave me the error that "Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Type<{}>'.

So I'm stumped. How does one go about returning a dynamically typed object in typescript?

```
import { Injectable, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, ElementRef,
         EventEmitter, OnInit, ComponentRef, ComponentFactoryResolver,
         Type, ReflectiveInjector } from '@angular/core';
import { WizardModalComponent } from './wizard-modal/wizard-modal.component'


@Injectable()
export class ModalGeneratorService {

  constructor(private _cmpFctryRslvr: ComponentFactoryResolver, private _vcRef: ViewContainerRef) {}

  private createModalComponent (compType : Type<Component>, vCref: ViewContainerRef): ComponentRef<compType> {
    let factory = this._cmpFctryRslvr.resolveComponentFactory(compType);
    // vCref is needed cause of that injector..
    let injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders([], vCref.parentInjector);
    // create component without adding it directly to the DOM
    let comp = factory.create(injector);
    return comp;
  }

  createWizardModalcomponent(vCref : ViewContainerRef) {
    createModalComponent(WizardModalComponent, vCref);
  }
}
```

Comment: Does returning an interface can be a solution?

Comment: @SebastienDErrico So long as the function accepts a component type as an input and returns a ComponentRef for that type, I'll be happy. If I have to nest that ComponentRef in an interface, so be it. Not sure how to do that either, though.

Comment: I think it's telling you "can't find compType", because the declared return type of the function is "<compType>". I don't think it's resolving that, I think maybe you're trying to get the function to change its return type based on what is fed into it (your incoming arg "compType")? Not sure that will work. For the sake of it, since this function basically can return any type, if you try <T> or some such instead of compType, what happens? You could also try returning an interface.

Comment: @TimConsolazio, if you take another look at my question, you'll see it's the second thing I tried. It resulted in this error: "Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Type<{}>'.

Comment: Ah, how about returning the interface (sorry I did actually read your whole question, I did not scroll the code box). That failure actually makes sense though. I'd look for a higher level interface to return? If you go with "any", how's that effect it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thank you everyone who commented or answered, I found an answer that works exactly the way I want and it is very simple.

I simply use the 'any' type in place of the component type for component ref, like so:

```
private createModalComponent (compType : Type<Component>, vCref: ViewContainerRef): ComponentRef<any> { ... }
```

At times like these, it always helps to remember that, although Typescript generally uses static typing, it is merciful enough to grant us the 'any' keyword. Hope someone else finds this useful.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure I understand the problem fully, but this might work:

```
private createModalComponent<T extends Type<{}>> (compType : T, vCref: ViewContainerRef): ComponentRef<T> { ... }
```

So you're declaring a generic type but restraining it to either *be* or extend the `Type<{}>` type, which is what the second error you had was saying.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the answer so posting it here:

I looked in the file ComponentFactory from the angular 2 framework itself; it uses "any", but further in, here is how it declares the create function (note the "<C>"):

```
create(injector: Injector, projectableNodes?: any[][], rootSelectorOrNode?: string|any) : ComponentRef<C>
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ComponentFactory-class.html